# Was Lor San Tekka watching over her?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

At the start of *Star Wars: The Force Awakens*, we're introduced to Lor San Tekka, who the *[Star Wars Databank](http://www.starwars.com/databank/lor-san-tekka)* describes as:

> A legendary traveler and explorer, Lor San Tekka is a longtime ally of the New Republic and the Resistance. After the Battle of Endor, San Tekka helped Luke Skywalker recover secret Jedi lore that the Empire had tried to erase, and Leia Organa hopes the old scout can now help find her brother. Following decades of adventure, San Tekka retired to live simply on Jakku, where he follows the dictates of the once-forbidden Church of the Force. But his retirement is fated to be anything but peaceful.

Which means he's a longtime ally of our intrepid heroes.  Later it's revealed that

> Rey was left on Jakku, which is the same planet that Lor San Tekka retired to.

Was this purely a coincidence, or was he there to keep tabs on her?

Comment: I'm going to take a guess at "Nothing official either way yet, wait for more stories to find out", but I have nothing to back this up.

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely no canon information to confirm that fact **at the moment**.

Chances are, he was not, since the canon information already posted a sizable chunk of Rey's past info, and it would seem (this is a subjective opinion) that inserting Tekka there to enrich the backstory would be an obvious solution:

- Rey's pages in Visual Dictionary
- Databank entries for both of them
- Novelization by Foster
- A prequel novel "Before the Awakening" dealing with Rey's past

  This is especially interesting, since Lor San Tekka **is mentioned** in that novel - but in Poe's part of 3 stories, NOT in Rey's part.
- As half a evidence, the prequel also says this about him: at least, Leia didn't know where he was. Of course, she didn't know Rey was on Jakku either, apparently, so it may not matter.

  > “We obtained a lot of information from the computers aboard Hevurion Grace,” Leia said, looking at the chip. “A wealth of information. But there was something else, something that…others may have missed. A piece of a puzzle I’ve been working for…for a long time to solve.”
  >   She set the data chip in Poe’s palm.
  >   “I think the First Order is trying to solve it, too, Poe. We have to solve it first. **We have to find him first**.”
  >   “Who?”
  >   “**His name is Lor San Tekka.**”
  >   “Lor San Tekka,” Poe repeated. “Why’s the First Order so desperate to find him?”
  >   “They think he knows something. I’m hoping he does, too.” Leia took his hand and folded his fingers closed over the data chip. She met his eyes. “I’m hoping Lor San Tekka knows where to find my brother, Poe. And Luke Skywalker may be the only hope we have left.”